# WPSM54G (Linksys printserver) not working on Mac OSx

Tags: mac, printer, print-server

I'm trying to have a wps54gworking on a mac os x. I have read a lot of stuff about this, but nothing seems to work and I don't understand why. The strange thing is that it work on mac os x, because a lot of people did this.

The printer is connected to the printserver with a USB cable

**This is what I have:**

- Notebook with Mac OS x
- WPSM54G
- Canon Pixma MP750 printer

Can someone give the the right way how to do this?

**Answer what worked for me:**

> Background: 1) Configure the print
>   server and successfully print from
>   windows (I don't know of another way)
>
> 2) I am running and printing on
>   10.5.6, using both methods below.
>
> 2) Download and install Gimp-Printing
>   for Mac OS X. Check to make sure your
>   printer is supported.
>
> 3) Download and install nmap\zenmap
>   for OS X. This is a useful tool for
>   discovery and what I used to find
>   ports and there uses.
>
> 4) I had some luck with LPD printing,
>   but only on the first print. After
>   that the printer printed garbage on
>   more pages than what I requested. NOT
>   OPTIMAL!
>
> Now you are free to print from either
>   (or both) ways as setup below.
>
> IPP Printing Protocol: Internet
>   Printing Protocol - IPP Address: The
>   network address of your WPSM54G + port
>   631 (192.168.1.149:631) Queue: ipp/P1
>   Name: ipp/P1 Print Using: Select your
>   printer here.
>
> Click Add.
>
> Now select the printer in the printer
>   and fax config dialog and go to the
>   options and supplies area
>
> Change the name to something useful (I
>   used "R320 - IPP")
>
> Change the location to "IP_" + the
>   network name for your print server (LK
>   and the last 6 characters of the MAC
>   address) But you can get this from
>   your router, nmap/zenmap by scanning
>   the address of the print server, or
>   just create it from the method in the
>   parenthesis above + "P1"
>
> So to clarify my location would be:
>   "IP_LKA040BAP1"
>
> Click okay, and print away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partially because most of the existing documentation is windows centric.  You can bypass their install tool, but it involves a few steps.  It is completely operating system independent.  You should be able to set it up the same way on Windows, Mac or *nix.

You can find the procedure [here](http://sites.google.com/site/daveparillo/misc/wpsm54g).

Let me know if there's anything in these instructions that don't work or aren't right.

Comment: thank you for your reply, the only thing is, how can I get this to work on a Apple Mac OSx?

Comment: Follow the instructions in the answer, then you can direct your computer to the printer using this: http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.5/en/8670.html or this: http://howto.ccs.neu.edu/howto/printing/adding-a-printer-to-mac-osx/

Comment: wednesday I'll go to this man and see if your sollution works.

Comment: I have edited my question with a answer on my own question